# How can i get make a table model work efficiently?

Tags: python, django, web

So,i am making an app for making timetables. and i have  run into a problem.
I have two models . Timetable and Content.

```
class Timetable(models.Model):

title=models.CharField(max_length=50)
start_time=models.TimeField(default="8:0")
end_time=models.TimeField(default="4:0")
entries=models.IntegerField(default=3)
theme=models.ForeignKey(Theme,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absoulte_url(self):
    return reverse('timetable-detail',args=[str(self.id)])

class CellEntry(models.Model):

parent_table=models.ForeignKey(Timetable,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
content=models.CharField(max_length=30)

def __str__(self):
    return self.content
```

How can i make a form such that i can get the two models to behave like a table in excel? How can i set the value of multiple cellentry's parent_table attribute to be the same value in a view?

Comment: django formset can help you

Answer (score 0):

So, what you want here is the form with cellEntry to be the parent with multiple child timetable.

Comment: I want the timetable to have multiple cellentry children

Comment: Get the cellEntry as a foreign key inside timetable model and use model_formset factory for cellEntry. You can check django doc to understand model_formset factory. I have added a sample code so you can get some idea. if you have any problem feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample code. Guess you can get some idea from here.

```
def content_add_view(request):

LectureFormset = modelformset_factory(Lecture, fields=('lecture_title', 'lecture_content', 'youtube_url'))

# if the request is post and the form is valid than save the form
if request.method == 'POST':
    content_add_form = ContentAddForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    formset = LectureFormset(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

    if content_add_form.is_valid():
        course = content_add_form.save(commit=False)
        course.user = request.user
        course.save()

        # looping through the formset as we need multiple fields saving it in same form. here we get the data and than save it 
        if formset.is_valid():
            for f in formset:
                try:
                    video = Lecture(course=course, lecture_title=f.cleaned_data.get('lecture_title'), lecture_content=f.cleaned_data.get('lecture_content'), youtube_url=f.cleaned_data.get('youtube_url'))
                    video.save()

                except Exception as e:
                    break
            return redirect('teacher-profile')
        else:
            print('formsset is invalid')

else:
    content_add_form = ContentAddForm()
    formset = LectureFormset(queryset=Lecture.objects.none())

context = {

    'contentForm': content_add_form,
    'formset': formset,
}

return render(request, 'apps/contentAdd.html', context)
```